# mosquitto broker with ssl LetsEncrypt certificate and self signed client certificate

Tags: lets-encrypt, mosquitto, client-certificates

I read already about this but I am not sure I got it correctly.

The situation is I have LetsEncrypt certificates for ssl for my duckdns server.

I wanted to reuse it for a mosquitto server as well, I configured it as

```
listener 8884

allow_anonymous false
password_file /mosquitto/config/passwords
certfile /mosquitto/ssl/live/xxxxxx.duckdns.org/fullchain.pem
keyfile /mosquitto/ssl/live/xxxxxx.duckdns.org/privkey.pem
tls_version tlsv1.2
```

where the certfile and keyfile are the ones generated by LetsEncrypt. This works as expected.

Now to expose it to the web though, I'd rather use client certificates.
For what I understood, I should use then a "private" CA, otherwise any certificate signed by LetsEncrypt would do as a valid client.

So I added to the configuration the following lines

```
require_certificate true
use_identity_as_username true
cafile /mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
```

Where ca.crt is a certificate I generated with

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 36500 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
```

and with it generated a client certificate using

```
openssl genrsa -out keyfile.key 4096
openssl req -new -key keyfile.key -out keyfile.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 36500 -in keyfile.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out keyfile.crt
```

I checked that the client certificate is correctly signed using openssl verify.
Now by calling

```
 mosquitto_pub --cafile /mosquitto/certs/ca.crt --key keyfile.key --cert keyfile.crt -h xxxxxx.duckdns.org -p 8884 -t broker/hello -m "online"
```

I get a TLS error and in mosquitto logs I see

```
OpenSSL Error[0]: error:1404A418:SSL routines:ST_ACCEPT:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
```

I suppose I'm mixing up things with the server certificate and the client certificate having different CAs, though I'm not getting where I'm doing it wrong and how to reach the goal.

Any help or hint on what's wrong in my operations, is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the CA cert you've passed to the `mosquitto_pub` command.

mosquitto_pub uses the ca cert passed to it to verify the certificate the broker presents to authenticate it's self, so it should point to somewhere that has the Let's Encrypt root CA. The CA cert should not be linked to the cert/key the client uses to authenticate.

So you should probably be pointing it at the system CA cert bundle e.g.

```
mosquitto_pub --capath /etc/ssl/certs --key keyfile.key --cert keyfile.crt -h xxxxxx.duckdns.org -p 8884 -t broker/hello -m "online"
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my mistake. For who will see this and needs to use the single file with --cafile (e.g. to connect from devices not having /etc/ssl/certs), the certificate can be obtained from https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem (source https://letsencrypt.org/certificates)

Comment: @AlessandroPerla This comment saved my life! wish the documentation could have indicated this more clearly, or if mac had an equivalent to `/etc/ssl/certs` that would automatically contain the keys like what works on linux if you give sub/pub the `--capath` option